# Error in transforms.js:17 during Angular building project

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an old project and I want to build it.
when I do ng serve I got:

```
[error] ...folders\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\schema\transforms.js:17
    value ??= schema.default;
          ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Zendbook\Documents\dilau_new\EmphaSoft-master1\EmphaSoft-master\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\schema\index.js:37:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
```

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.13
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1702.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.2.0
@angular-devkit/core            17.2.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.2.0
@angular/cli                    17.2.0
@schematics/angular             17.2.0
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.3.3
```

I tried delete npm_modules folder and did npm install.
Please advise...

Comment: Which command did you run to produce the result in the below block? Looks a bit strange, it says Angular CLI version is v14 on top but below it says Angular v17. You can try using a more recent Node version

Comment: I did ng serve and after I see 
An unhandled exception occurred: Unexpected token '??='
See "C:\Users\Zendbook\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-FGm6IR\angular-errors.log" for further details. 
This is text of the error from angular-errors.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your NodeJs version?
Check it in the console `node -v`.

I assume you have a version less than 15

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment

Comment: yes, I use 14.15.0

Comment: Embrace the version 15 or more :)